# ItemDataBound Called twice on delete command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, itemdatabound

I ve an issue with a listview.

Im doing that when delete button is clicked in the listview:(code simplified, it delete as it should)

```
Protected Sub rlvCarts_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As RadListViewCommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = RadListView.DeleteCommandName Then
                           mylistItem.items.RemoveAt(e.CommandArgument.ToString)                    
            BindData()            
        End If
End Sub

 Protected Sub BindData()
     rlvCarts.DataSource = mylistItem.items
     rlvCarts.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

The issue comes when deleteting it will perform itemdatabound twice (but listview prerender once).

How does it come? How can I avoid that?

Comment: This mix up names is lead to bugs. Use the IsPostBack in the correct point to avoid this twice call.

Comment: you might be calling  BindData()   on pageload also, without apply !ispostback

Comment: I'm testing postback as it should (beside listview prerender is called once)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I had to add `e.Canceled = True`

```
Protected Sub rlvCarts_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As RadListViewCommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = RadListView.DeleteCommandName Then
                           mylistItem.items.RemoveAt(e.CommandArgument.ToString)   
            e.Canceled = True     
            BindData()            
        End If
End Sub
```

It prevents the **"auto rebind"** when a command is called